# How to set the machine or user keystore with .NET Core and RSA encryption

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, encryption, .net-core

We have ported a .NET Framework library to .NET Standard 2.0.  The previous library allowed the user to specify whether to use the user or machine keystore using the CspParameters class and RSACryptoServiceProvider class.  For example:

```
    CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();
    csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keyLength, csp);
```

When porting to .NET Standard 2.0, we no longer use RSACryptoServiceProvider and use the RSA base class:

```
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.KeySize = keyLength;
```

I don't see a way to specify a machine keystore or a user keystore as we did when using RSACryptoServiceProvider. Is there a way to specify this?

I see this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-3.0) that seems to state this is handled for you with ASP.NET Core.  Is this the case?  What about for Desktop Core applications?

Comment: The concept of the machine/user key store as used by CSP providers is specific to Windows. ASP.NET Core apparently solves its own problems, without relying on this, though you could use the `Microsoft.AspNet.Core.DataProtection` package even in desktop applications (if you wire up the dependencies right). What's your ultimate goal -- is backwards compatibility with existing clients on Windows needed? If so, you'll almost certainly have to keep `RSACryptoServiceProvider` around anyway, even if just behind a platform check.

Comment: Backwards compatibility with existing clients is not needed.  
I did not create the original assembly and only worked on porting it to .NET Standard. I'm not well-versed with the machine/user keystore, but I do understand it is only on Windows.  It does sound like ASP.NET Core takes care of things for you.  Which keystore would a .NET Core desktop application use by default? The original assembly allows setting the keystore and recommends the user keystore for desktop applications.

Comment: There is no cross-platform concept of a keystore (that I'm aware of), so there would not be any default for a .NET Core desktop application to use. This is why ASP.NET Core has to "reinvent the wheel" for itself by combining various methods into one approach that works for "all" ASP.NET Core sites. You'll have to decide if you want to keep the concept of a "keystore" around and if so, how you'd want to implement it. My recommendation would be to either cut this functionality altogether, or else just roll with what ASP.NET Core does (it's not a particularly easy wheel to reinvent).

Comment: If you didn’t have a name associated with the CSP then the machine store flag didn’t have any effect... it’s just for where to save/load persisted (named) keys.